# Blender Animation

Tags: animation

Do you have some suggestions or ideas on how to make this kind of animation. Specifically on how in the example the DNA splits and the other part joins in between? How to go about this?

I'm pasting some example pictures and video here (0.45 - 0.50 in video)

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MucL_RlbnE

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Give a *Curve* modifier to objects 1, 2 and 3 with 2 curves as *Curve Object*:

[image]

Push away objects 2 and 3:

[image]

Move the object 1 and its curve until it matches:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast response and time! Helped a lot :)